# Socket UDP- Program stops at recvfrom

Tags: c++, matlab, sockets, recvfrom

I try to send data via UDP from a computer to another (first Computer: Ubuntu, C++ with Eclipse, second Computer Windows 10 Matlab 2014b). The C++ computer should work as server. Sending data from C++ to Matlab works fine, but i am not able to send data in opposite direction. Every time my C++ program reaches recvfrom() it will idle at this point without doing anything anymore, even if matlab is sending data over and over againg. I tried to receive data on ubuntu via netcat while sending the packages with Matlab and that works fine as well. Even i tried something with select() but this only resulted in waiting for 10s when program reaches select() and then freezes at recvfrom again. I would be very grateful if someone can give me some help.

```
int Socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
/*FD_ZERO(&SockSet);
FD_SET(Socket,&SockSet);
sTimeval.tv_sec=0.1;
sTimeval.tv_usec=0;
int status=select(Socket+1,&SockSet,(fd_set*)NULL,(fd_set *)NULL,&sTimeval);
cout<<status<<endl;*/

if(Socket!=-1)
cout<<"Socket created"<<endl;
else
cout<<"Socket not created"<<endl;

unsigned short port=4012;

struct in_addr serverIP;
//(void)inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.56.100", &clientIP);
(void)inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.56.101", &serverIP);

struct sockaddr_in server;
memset(&server,0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.sin_addr=serverIP;
server.sin_port=htons(port);


if(bind(Socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(&server))!=1)
cout<<"Binding successful"<<endl;
else
cout<<"Binding failed";


struct sockaddr client;
memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
socklen_t clientlen=0;
struct sockaddr_in* client_in;
memset(&client_in,0,sizeof(client_in));


cout<<"warten vor recv"<<endl;
ssize_t bytesread=recvfrom(Socket, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, &client,&clientlen);
cout<<(int)bytesread<<endl;
cout<<msg<<endl;


client_in=(struct sockaddr_in*)&client;
char* client_adr=inet_ntoa(client_in->sin_addr);
printf("%s Port%d\n", client_adr, ntohs(client_in->sin_port));


if (bytesread == -1) {
cerr << "Fehler beim empfangen" << endl;
int status = close(Socket);
if (status == 0)
cout << "Socket closed" << endl;
else if (status == -1)
cout << "Socket not closed" << endl;
return (1);

}


//Wenn Infos ueber Client nicht schon vorher aus recvfrom()
/*struct in_addr clientIP;
(void)inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.2.102", &clientIP);
struct sockaddr_in client;
memset(&client,0, sizeof(client));
client.sin_family=AF_INET;
client.sin_addr=clientIP;
client.sin_port=htons(portwindows);*/


char msg2[]="12345";
ssize_t bytessent=sendto(Socket,msg2,strlen(msg2),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizeof(client));
cout<<(int)bytessent<< " bytes were sent"<<endl;



int status=close(Socket);
if(status==0)
cout<<"Socket closed"<<endl;
else if(status==-1)
cout<<"Socket not closed"<<endl;
```

Comment: 192.168.56.101, is that the unix box or the matlab box?

Comment: If you don't want recvfrom() to block until some data has been received, then you'll want to set your socket to non-blocking mode.  (Search for nonblocking on this site's search box and you'll see lots of questions and answers about how to do that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried already to set my socket in the non-blocking mode and after hat my program was not freezing anymore. But the problem is that i am sending data via Matlab so recvfrom() should get some data and then the program should go further. But can you see why this is not happen? As i said, when i send data via matlab and test it with netcat whether the data reaches the c++ computer everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

After running the program in Debug mode suddenly the program is passing recvfrom, but without receiving the data which was sent. Even if i run recvfrom in a while-loop and send constantly data to the port recvfrom never get a package. If i try to run listen and accept before it (i know usally that is not necessary by udp connection) the functions both returns -1. But i can not see why my Socket is not ready to receive data. Maybe anynone have an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: After long search i solved the problem. There were to mistakes by binding the socket. Mistake 1: using sizeof(&server) instead of sizeof(server) and mistake 2: if bind... =!1 instead of -1. So binding the socket was never sucessfall but because of asking for wheter bind is =!1 the program told me binding was sucessful while it was not.